# WM_SIZE and WM_PAINT messages precedence

Tags: c, winapi

When both `WM_SIZE` and `WM_PAINT` messages are to be sent (for example: when I resize my window to a larger size), is it guaranteed that the `WM_SIZE` message will be sent before the `WM_PAINT` message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `WM_SIZE` is received first, and `WM_PAINT` will be send with the new size.

Actually, `WM_PAINT` is a *lazy* message (the other being `WM_TIMER`, IIRC): it is not actually sent to the message queue. Instead, when the window is invalidated, a flag is set, and when you call `GetMessage()` and there are no messages left in the queue, it checks the invalidation flag. If it is set, it will return a fabricated `WM_PAINT` message.

This has the effect of `WM_PAINT` having low priority, and effectively melds all the pending invalidations in a single redraw.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is *usually* a synthesized message like you describe.  However, `UpdateWindow()` and `RedrawWindow(RDW_UPDATENOW)` generate a real `WM_PAINT` message that is sent directly to the window immediately, bypassing the message queue. The window won't know the difference, it will simply paint when it is told to paint.